# Unable to register user - photo_id does not have a default value (Version 5.6)

Tags: laravel-5.6

I have my users and photos tables create. Now that I added the photo_id into my users table, I am unable to register a user and it gives me an error saying that photo_id does not have a default value.

Here my User Model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','photo_id'
    ];
    public function photo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Photo Model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Photo extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['path'];
}
```

Users Migration table

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('photo_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

And here My photo migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePhotosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('path');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('photos');
    }
}
```

This is what I see when I try to register a user:

[image]

Comment: That means you either create a user with a photo_id or you make the photo_id column nullable

Comment: I made the photo_id nullable and it works. Thank you so much